# How to run python script with its own dependencies in Java independently from JDK environment

Tags: python, java, numpy

I want to run script inside my Java code. More specifically, I want to implement GUI in Java and run python script to get make heavy lifting work that I want to do only with python and get result in java and show it to the user in GUI.

I tried some examples on the internet by creating its own environment for python and connecting it to the python script but it seems like there is problem with architecture.

The error from numpy library:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64)))


ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
```

This is my Java code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            setupPythonEnvironment();
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("python3", "/Users/ilhomsoliev/Desktop/WebApplications/PythonInJavaRun/src/python_scripts/main.py");
            Process process = builder.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader readerError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            String lines = null;
            while ((lines = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(lines);
            }
            while ((lines = readerError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(lines);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static void setupPythonEnvironment(){
        try {
            // Path to your Python script's directory
            String scriptDir = "/Users/ilhomsoliev/Desktop/WebApplications/PythonInJavaRun/src/python_scripts";
            String requirementsPath = scriptDir + "/requirements.txt";

            // Create a virtual environment
            String venvDir = scriptDir + "/venv";
            executeCommand("python3 -m venv " + venvDir);

            // Install dependencies from requirements.txt
            String pipInstallCmd = venvDir + "/bin/pip3 install -r " + requirementsPath; // for Unix-based systems
            executeCommand(pipInstallCmd);

            System.out.println("Python environment set up successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static void executeCommand(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
        pb.inheritIO(); // To show the output/error in Java console
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor(); // Wait for the process to finish
    }
}
```

This is requirments.txt:

```
pip
site-packages
numpy
moviepy
pacman
```

Comment: Hard to answer unless you add details of how you launch Python directly and via Java.

Comment: @DuncG, I added code for Java.

Comment: What's your CPU architecture? e.g. arm64 or x86_64?

Comment: @NickODell Apple Silicon M1 chip, ARM-based Architecture.